# Coding was running though it didn't show the output. Maybe it would be the scanf problem? I'm not sure

Tags: c

Hello I'm the beginner of programming c. I'm studying c with the book and doing copy the book for basic learning. Some coding was running and showed the output but Some coding also was running tho didn't show the output. Can you help me? this is my first question of coding and I'm not really good at English so sorry for not including details about my question.

This is my code and this was running but didn't give output:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    double num1, num2;
    printf("print: ");
    scanf("%lf %lf", &num1, &num2);

    printf("plus: %f \n", num1+num2);
    return 0;

}
```

This is not only running but also gave output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("hello world\n");`

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What was the input you used? This seems to work: https://ideone.com/t7iPWx

Comment: *How* are you running your program? What environment are you using? Does the first example not give any output at all, not even the `print:` prompt?

Comment: Add `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf("print: ");`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does printf not flush after the call unless a newline is in the format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin)

Comment: Did running the first code terminate without output? Or did you start it, did not see any output and then terminated it forcefully?

Comment: I did fflush(stdout); but it didn't work.

Comment: I just right-clicked and clicked the 'run code'. I'm using visual studio code at MacBook and yes it didn't give any output at all

Comment: @ChrisHongPlease [edit] your question and add requested information or clarification there. Please also show the input you used.